# Imported Dependency Module Classes are not seen LibGDX inside Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I am using libgdx inside an android app as fragment and this is how my project structure looks like:
[image]

**What i am trying to do is call module "app" classes from module "my-gdx-game-core"** So that i can communicate between libGDX game and android app.

By the way i can call `my-gdx-game-android` **from** `app` and `my-gdx-game-core` **from** `my-gdx-game-android.` So that i can start game inside android  fragment.

Eventhough i added app as dependency to my-gdx-game-core its not seen.Gradle sync is succesfull but i just cant access classes for some reason.Also if i right click "my-gdx-game-core" module and check dependencys from android studio i can see app there.

[image]

build.gradle for Project:LibGDXInAndroidKotlin:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project.ext {
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle for Module app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion project.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ersen.androidwithlibgdx"
        minSdkVersion project.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":my-gdx-game-android")
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.gauravk.bubblenavigation:bubblenavigation:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.anastr:speedviewlib:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

build.gradle for my-gdx-game-android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    implementation project(":my-gdx-game-core")

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:${project.gdxVersion}"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:${project.gdxVersion}:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:${project.gdxVersion}:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:${project.gdxVersion}:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:${project.gdxVersion}:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:${project.gdxVersion}:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives {
    doFirst {
        file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86/").mkdirs()

        configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
            def outputDir = null
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
            if(outputDir != null) {
                copy {
                    from zipTree(jar)
                    into outputDir
                    include "*.so"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { packageTask ->
    if (packageTask.name.contains("package")) {
        packageTask.dependsOn 'copyAndroidNatives'
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', '%PACKAGE%/%PACKAGE%.AndroidLauncher'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**And here the important one build.gradle for my-gdx-game-core**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':app', configuration: 'default')

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:${project.gdxVersion}"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"


}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

As you see i added

```
implementation project(path: ':app', configuration: 'default')
```

and it syncs succesfully.By the way if i add just

```
implementation project(':app')
```

gradle throws project not resolved error i dont know what is the difference.

**Anyway even i added dependency i cant access classes of module 'app'.**

I have already tried invalidate caches restart

Edit::::

GameActivity class inside `app` which starts `my-gdx-game-android`'s fragment

```
class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val libgdxGameFragment:AndroidGameFragment = AndroidGameFragment()




        //never mind if this supportFragmentManager... shows type mismatch error.Its working. this line puts libgdx into fragment.fragment is similar to component in react.
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, libgdxGameFragment, AndroidGameFragment::class.java.simpleName).commit()


    }




    override fun exit() {

    }
      fun myFun(){

    }
}
```

AndroidGameFragment inside     my-gdx-game-android which starts my-gdx-game-core(actual libgdx game)

```
class AndroidGameFragment () : AndroidFragmentApplication(){



    


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()




        return initializeForView(MyGdxGame(), config)
    }

 




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cyclical relationship there...two different modules that are dependent on each other. I don't think that will work.

LibGDX projects are typically set up with a core module that is platform independent, and then android and desktop modules that depend on the the core. This allows you to very rapidly iterate on the desktop without having to compile and install Android builds over and over through most of your development process.

If you truly don't care about the benefits of being able to test on your computer, you don't need a core module at all. You would just put everything into Android. What you're trying to do now effectively defeats the purpose of having a separate core module.

However, I would recommend keeping them separate, in case you ever change your mind or decide to port to other platforms like iOS.

If you need to call android specific code from `core`, you don't need to depend on the `android` module. You can create an interface that is passed to your game constructor. For example, if you want to display an Android Toast, you could make an interface like this in `core`:

```
public interface PlatformAdapter {
    void showToast(String message);
}
```

In your game, capture a reference to it from your constructor and call the adapter when you want Android to do something:

```
private PlatformAdapter adapter;

public MyGame (PlatformAdapter adapter){
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

void showToast(String message){
    if (adapter != null) adapter.showToast(message);
}
```

Then in your `android` module, you can pass an adapter into your game. For example:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements PlatformAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.r = 8;
        config.g = 8;
        config.b = 8;
        config.a = 8;
        config.useWakelock = true;
        initialize(new MyGame(this), config);
    }

    @Override
    public void showToast(String message){
        runOnUiThread( new Runnable(){ public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }});
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. This explains how to communicate between android and core. So lets say that i have a Socket class in app and i would like to use its object from core. So lets say i communicated with core and android with the interface method, how am i gonna communicate between android and app so that i can use app's Socket classes object ? I cant reach app from android(fragment) via getActivity() it doenst see app's activity methods. Basically i have a activity inside app which starts android via supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction() ... I am adding them to my initial question

Comment: Im just moving fragment android to app

Comment: A fragment can call through to the Activity's methods after it is attached to the activity, which happens a little bit after `fragment.onCreateView()`, so you can use guarded (null check on activity) calls. You can make your Fragment implement the interface for the game to call. For example with my toast example you could have `override fun showToast(message:String) = activity?.let{Toast.makeText(it, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)}`

Comment: I should add that I've oversimplified. You can't call Android UI methods directly from the game thread, so actually it should be `override fun showToast(message:String) = activity?.let{it.runOnUiThread{Toast.makeText(it, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)}}`